# How can I hide or show fields using states with hook form alter

Tags: 8, javascript

We have been using Field States UI module with some success, but the Comparison Value does always not work for multiple values, I have tried to modify the valuse right in the entity_form_display.node yml file but no luck. I will also try the Conditional Fields module for D8. I also want to try to do this using code. I am trying an example using hook form alter taken from this post. But I cant get it to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380720/drupal-8-conditional-field. Should I be using drupal_process_states instead? Here is my code, I have two term reference fields field_test2 and field_test3. If you select the term id 15 from field_test2 then field_test3 will become visible.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function mymodule_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) { 

  if ($form_id == 'node_page_form' || $form_id == 'node_page_edit_form') {
    return;
  }

  if (isset($form['field_test2'])) {
    $states_when_category_is_design = array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_test2"]' => array('value' => '15'),
      ),
    );

    if (isset($form['field_test3'])) {
      $form['field_test3']['#states'] = $states_when_category_is_design;
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems you re using the Drupal 7 syntax. For Drupal 8 this is slightly different.

You can implement hook_form_alter() as follows to change the visibility state of a form element as follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'node_article_edit_form') {  
    $form['field_other']['#states'] = [
      'visible' => [
          'select[name="field_reason"]' => ['value' => 'other']
      ]
    ];
   }
 }
```

This will make the **field_other** field visible if the **other** option is chosen in the **reason** select list.

Answer (score 4):

I use this to display or hide fields with dependency in a dropdown select list.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_CONTENT_TYPE_form' || $form_id == 'node_CONTENT_TYPE_edit_form') {
    conditional_field_select(
      $form,
      'field_target',
      'field_controller',
      ['value_a', 'value_b', 'value_c'],
      'visible'
    );
  }
}

function conditional_field_select(array &$form, $targetField, $controlledBy, array $values, $state = 'invisible', $cond = 'or') {
  if (isset($form[$targetField]) && isset($form[$controlledBy])) {
    $form[$targetField]['#states'][$state] = [];
    foreach ($values as $value) {
      array_push($form[$targetField]['#states'][$state], ['select[name=' . $controlledBy . ']' => ['value' => $value]]);
      if (end($values) !== $value) {
        array_push($form[$targetField]['#states'][$state], $cond);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It can easily be changed to input.

```
array_push($form[$targetField]['#states'][$state], [':input[name=' . $controlledBy . ']' => ['value' => $value]]);
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using #states for in a node form, with this code for Drupal 8 this is slightly different.

You can implement hook_form_alter() as follows to change the visibility state of a form element as follows:

```
/**
*Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'node_article_edit_form') { 
  $form['field_other']["widget"][0]['#states'] = [
    'visible' => [
      'input[name="field_reason[value]"]' => ['checked' => TRUE]
    ]
  ];
 }
}
```

This will make the field_other field visible if the checked option is chosen in the reason checknox.