# Display a block based on current select option

Tags: 8, javascript, blocks

I have a select field that holds two options. When the second option is chosen, I want to display a block.

I know that with form API I should be able to do this. I'm just not sure on where to start. Any help getting me going would be greatly appreciated.

So far I have the code below.

```
function MODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['account']['type'] = [
      '#title' => 'I am ordering for',
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => [ 'Myself' => 'Myself', 'Someone' => 'Someone else' ],
      '#weight' => -100
      ];
}
```

Comment: Is that block going to be part of the form, i.e. showing further information that need to be submitted on form-submit?

Comment: you are using drupal8 or drupal7

Comment: Hi, @sivani I'm using Drupal 8.

Comment: @theuni, it will be part of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to add the fields in a form alter hook. Do this in the field UI of the user entity `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`. To change the visibility of fields dependending on the content of another field use

[Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)

or the Form #states API directly, see [How can I hide or show fields using states with hook form alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230045/how-can-i-hide-or-show-fields-using-states-with-hook-form-alter).

**EDIT:** The form #states api did the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not displaying another field. I'm trying to show and hide a block.

Comment: These are two ways to show and hide elements on a page with javascript. This can also be a block, this is technically the same, only different CSS to make it look like a block.

Comment: got it. yep, I did a bit more research on the #states form API info and I believe that's the way for me to go.